# Infinite scroll mechanism for a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculated-field

I'm trying to build a scroll mechanism for a calendar where people can scroll infinite back and forth (don't ask me why :-) ). I want JavaScript to add a 'slide' with the correct month before the shown last month. So I need JavaScript to know that for example December comes before January and also what year it is.

I know its pretty difficult but maybe somebody can help me a little further :-)

My code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/villete/p85gv0tt/

```
function createPrevMonth(){

    var $slide = $('<div/>', {
        'class' : 'slide',
    }).prependTo($slideWrapper);

    $('<a/>', {
        'href'  : '#',
        'html'  : 'Month',
    }).appendTo($slide);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any date library like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?